# Send an email with attachment Client Agnostic

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I currently have an application written that generates pdf vouchers and emails to their perspective recipients. However the function I use is client dependent (MS Outlook) and I would really like to make this email client agnostic as we have many customers and not all of them use Outlook.

I have looked at a few options but can't really find anything in searching that seems to solve my problem.

Does anyone know a good way to send email using the customers smtp connection regardless of the client and send an attachment with it without calling the client directly to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or you can use the [Synapse](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/features) library, for sending a mail using SMTP, ideally in its [newest snapshot](http://synalist.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/synalist/trunk.tar.gz?view=tar).

Here is the code which should send the mail with attached `c:\voucher.pdf` file from `sender@from.com` to `recipient@to.com` to the `smtp.server.com` with login `login` and password `password`. About the rest of the functions from the `TMimeMess` class I would refer you directly to [the reference](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doc/help/mimemess.TMimeMess.html).

I hope this will work because I've simplified and localized much more complicated code I'm using and I can't verify it nor compile. If not, let's downvote it :)

```
uses
  SMTPSend, MIMEPart, MIMEMess;

procedure TForm.SendEmailClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  MIMEText: TStrings;
  MIMEPart: TMimePart;
  MIMEMessage: TMimeMess;
begin
  MIMEText := TStringList.Create;
  MIMEText.Add('Hello,');
  MIMEText.Add('here is the text of your e-mail message,');
  MIMEText.Add('if you want the HTML format, use AddPartHTML');
  MIMEText.Add('or e.g. AddPartHTMLFromFile if you have your');
  MIMEText.Add('HTML message content in a file.');

  MIMEMessage := TMimeMess.Create;

  with MIMEMessage do
  try
    Header.Date := Now;
    Header.From := 'sender@from.com';
    Header.ToList.Clear;
    Header.ToList.Add('recipient@to.com');
    Header.CcList.Clear;
    Header.Subject := 'E-mail subject';
    Header.XMailer := 'My mail client name';

    MIMEPart := AddPartMultipart('mixed', nil);

    AddPartText(MIMEText, MIMEPart);
    AddPartBinaryFromFile('c:\voucher.pdf', MIMEPart);

    EncodeMessage;

    if SendToRaw(Header.From,               // e-mail sender
                 Header.ToList.CommaText,   // comma delimited recipient list
                 'smtp.server.com',         // SMTP server
                 Lines,                     // MIME message data
                 'login',                   // server authentication
                 'password')                // server authentication
    then
      ShowMessage('E-mail has been successfuly sent :)')
    else
      ShowMessage('E-mail sending failed :(');
  finally
    Free;
    MIMEText.Free;
  end;
end;
```

*Update:*

According to nice comment from [Downvoter step into the light](https://stackoverflow.com/users/759588/) (man, change your nick please, it's not cool anymore :), would be really bad if you will send the list of all recipients to everyone. With synapse [you cannot](http://www.ararat.cz/synapse/doku.php/public:howto:sendingbcc) add BCCs to the message header; there's no `Header.BCCList` property in `MIMEMessage`.
Instead you can directly modify the data before sending them.

```
// First, you will remove the line where you are adding a recipient to the list
Header.ToList.Add('recipient@to.com');

// the rest between you can keep as it is and after the message encoding
EncodeMessage;

// and before sending the mail you'll insert the line with BCCs
Lines.Insert(1, 'Bcc: jane@invisiblecustomer.com, lisa@invisiblecustomer.com');

if SendToRaw ...
```

Comment: I'm going to give this route a shot. the cc wont be an issue. The application only sends a voucher to one recipient. The program generates 10-15 different vouchers and emails them to our customers clients. One recipient in the whole process. The current implementation using Outlook works like a charm but as stated not all are using outlook.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Indy](http://www.indyproject.org) as your SMTP client, independent of the system default e-mail client. Here's a basic [demo](http://www.atozed.com/indy/Demos/10/index.en.aspx) of sending e-mails without attachments, and there are detailed articles [here](http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/blogs/rlebeau/2005_08_17_a.en.aspx) and [here](http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/blogs/rlebeau/20080116.EN.aspx) about sending HTML or plain-text e-mails and with or without attachments.

Comment: But that wouldn't integrate with the user's email client (namely, he wouldn't be able to keep track of sent emails.) Not a simple design decision!

Comment: @Leonardo Of course it wouldn't integrate. If that's a requirement you could try MAPI - there's `JclMapi` in the [JCL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcl/) but then again, not all e-mail clients support it properly.

Comment: @Leonardo: James asked for SMTP, which is a protocol, not a program.  Indy has a `TIdSMTP` component that accesses the SMTP protocol directly, no other email client is needed since TIdSMTP *is* the client.  If he wants to track sent emails, he will have to do so manually (such as by connecting to his email server via the IMAP4 protocol - see the `TIdIMAP4` component - and uploading the email into a desired folder).

Comment: Agreed, IMAP is better, if it's available.

Comment: A pitfall of this approach is that it will require user intervention to use proxy/firewall in corporate/university environments and anti-malware apps like ZoneAlarm will actively block it until the user whitelists it.

Comment: @Remy - I know the OP said "the customer smtp connection" but I think the spirit of his question is "the customer email client." As you and others pointed, the solution could be IMAP but that can also be unreliable (many people just use plain old POP3.) That's why I said this is a tough design decision.

Comment: @Leonardo Herrera, that should be done in less crude way, eg: BCC

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate with the existent email client (e.g. see the sent messages in the `sent`, `sent items`, etc. folder of the email client), you could use [Simple MAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd296734%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). The headers are translated in the Mapi unit in Delphi (at least in D2007).

But be careful to check if the actual client supports Simple MAPI.

Comment: Inportant information on the linked Simple MAPI page: `The use of Simple MAPI is discouraged. It may be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions of Windows.`